# How to ssh into cloudstack SSVM through public IP address

Tags: apache-cloudstack

Is there anyone know how to ssh into cloudstack SSVM through public IP address?My hypervisor is KVM and I have binded public IP address to SSVM and I can ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.cloud -p 3922 root@,but I just can't ssh SSVM through public IP address.Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, for security reasons you cannot.  Use the management IP address instead.

PS.  This is probably a better question for ServerFault

Comment: But,if I insist in visiting SSVM by public IP,how can I configure the SSVM or management server?

Comment: You'd have to modify the SSVM.  You'd probably turn off iptables rules and you'd make sure the ssh config allowed it to listen on all NICs

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to Login to SSVM, then you can do it using **linklocalip of SSVM**.

First **SSH to your host** and then from the host, you can SSH to SSVM using linklocalip in the same manner (**ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.cloud -p 3922 root@linklocalipOfSSVM**)